# Convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(k+3)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble understanding this question. I took calculus 5 years ago.

> The following integral
>   $$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{(x+3)^2}=\frac14$$
>   is the area under the graph of $f(x)=\frac1{(x+3)^2}$ and to the right of $x=1$. For which values of $k$ does the following infinite series converge?
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(k+3)^2}$$

I need help getting started.

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question pretty heavily.  Please check to make sure I didn't change your meaning.  Also, you can click on "edit" to see the syntax I used.

Comment: As to the question it self, I don't understand it.  The sum $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{ (k+3)^2 }$ is a Riemann sum for the integral so you can use the one to estimate the other.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: @lulu thank you so much for editting the format. You didn't change any of the meaning. You made it more clear.

Comment: @Calilaun Actually I edited it, to clear the mess lulu did. -.-

Comment: @FourierTransform thank you too.

Comment: Maybe this will help?

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(k+3)^2} = \sum_{n = 4}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{49}{36}$$

Comment: @FourierTransform oh the p series. I forgot about that. Well I see that you substituted k + 3 = n. But when you evaluate the p series of n^2, and you get out pi^2 / 6 - 49/36, what happens to the k?

Comment: Is it that when it goes to infinity, k could be anything and that the convergence will always go to that number pi^2 / 6 - 49/36. Sorry calculus has been a while.

Comment: @Calilaun Nothing happens: when you substitute $n = k+3$ you automatically have to arrange the limits of the series: with $n$ it starts from $4$, not from $1$ as you can see! Then it's nothing but a translated Riemann Zeta function, and clearly since it starts from $4$ you have to subtract the terms from $1$ to $3$.

Comment: i just need to find the interval, and i'm lost as ever :(

Answer (score 0):

Much like the integral from $1$ to $\infty$, the series
$$
s = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+3)^2}
$$
has "bounds" of $1$ to $\infty$. However, let's replace the $\infty$ on the top of the capital sigma with a finite value $k$, and call that sum $s_k$. What we are really doing then is evaluating the *limit* of the sequence $s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots = (s_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$. As you said, the series is convergent and $s_n \to s$.

Comment: using integration, i would find that it would converge to 1/4. so now how would i find the left bound?

Comment: @Calilaun, I think I have misunderstood what you mean by left-bound. Would you please define that? I thought you meant the limits of summation, but I suspect that isn't the case.

Comment: i think the math question asks for the bounds on the left and right that contain the summation. I think 1/4 is one of the bounds since it's the limit that the integral goes to.

Comment: now i'm trying to find the other bound, so i could find the interval of the summation.

Comment: @Calilaun, So, do you want a lower-bound on the value of the sum? If that is the case, notice that the sequence $s_1, s_2, \ldots$ is increasing, so $s_1\le s_n$ for all $n > 1$.